# jQuery show neither html not working with $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="sign-up" id="sign-up">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name">
<label for="age">Age:</label>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Verify" id="submit-form">
  </form>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>

(function() {
$('form').on('submit',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#verify').slideUp();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"https://externalhost/file.php",//not the actual host
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
    $('#result').html(result); }
    });
});

})();
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make a subscription form for my visitors but I'm having trouble with it.

First of all, I can't check if all fields have been completed because it's showing the result, for example with .show().

Second, the $.ajax form it self it's working, I'm receiving all the info and everything it's being registered in MySql so the external file called via $.ajax it's fine also, but the result it's not being shown.

Also, this is going to be a Facebook App but it's not working out of Facebook either :/

Can anyone please help me, what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:

Though the # in the markup was a mistake, I fixed it but again it's not working :/

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your markup:

```
<div id="#result"></div>
```

should be

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

If your `result` is an object, using `html()` will not work. You can, however, have an `each()` function that loops through each object property and appends the value to your `#result` div.

```
$.each(result, function(key, element) {
  $("#result").append(key + ": " + element + "<br />");
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yn2Rr/2/).

Comment: Thanks but again the same :/

Comment: Can you post an example of what your result looks like? If it's an object, it will not work using `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass jQuery into your self-invoking function.  You can do it like this...

```
(function($) {
...

})(jQuery);
```

And make sure your loading the script file on your page somewhere before that all starts